# Are there English speaking countries for further studies where it's not necessary to be able to drive vehicles?

Tags: abroad

One thing that is stopping me from abroad studies is my lack of ability to drive. So, I was wondering if there are countries where it's not necessary to drive. Countries where public transportation is good in every part of the country.

Comment: Why…”in every part of the country”?

Answer (score 7):

Very few students in the UK have Cars. I've made it to 41, as a permenant faculty member without ever owning a car.

That doesn't mean that public transport is good in every part of the country. Far from it. University towns like Oxford and Cambridge are so small neither public nor private transport is generally neccessary, and most people cycle most places. London does require transport, but the public transport in London is some of the best in the world.

In the big northern cities like Sheffield, Leeds and Manchester, the cities are big enough to require transport, but generally students live within walking (or at least cycling) distance of the university campus.

Answer (score 6):

**Pretty much all of them**.

Just live in student housing. You'll usually be close enough to campus to be able to walk there, failing which the university is likely to have arranged for transport like shuttle buses to and from campus.

If you're interested in going places other than the university, then it becomes more complex - where do you want to go? How often? How far? - and that will depend on your exact requirements.

Comment: Indeed, OP likely has the US in mind, and yet in the US it's very common for college students and graduate students to not drive.

Comment: Much easier, however, if the university is in a large city (Madison, WI, say) rather than a rural place. And, one of the few places with good public transport helps. The US is mostly a failure in that department.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are posing too many strong assumptions.

English speaking countries is a too strong limiting factor.
There are countries like the Netherlands, or Denmark, or Luxembourg, where you can live (not just survive) only speaking English, and they have excellent public transport services [1].

With time, of course it will be better to learn the local language, but it is not necessary (although it is a bit of philosophical/ethic question, whether you should speak or not the local language).

If you then expand your search to countries where English is barely enough to survive, you may consider Japan, or Austria and Switerland, countries that made some gigantic passes (with respect to where they were) in understanding english in the past 20 years. Germany is also ok, if you end up in a big city (Berlin, Hamburg, Munich) you will be rather fine.

But overall, the requirement in being able to drive is not that common, unless you are doing environmental sciences stuff, where you are expected to be out "in the wild".

[1] excellent on a relative metric, relative to the English speaking countries. The Netherlands, for example, destroyed their network of local transport to small comunities ... it still exist and it does the job, but it was *way* better.

Answer (score 0):

No problems to live and study in one of the bigger cities in Germany. Public transport is quite good, and I know many people who live there (not only students) and do not own a car.

Edit: Many German universities offer programmes in English (and it is no problem to live in a German city if you speak only English), so you might consider this, too.

Comment: Germany is not an English speaking country.

Comment: Forgot to say that there are many degree programmes in English. I have edited my comment.